# Check if a date is within 30 days with Angular-cli pipes

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular2-pipe

How can I bring all the Events that begin inside this day to 30 days?
I'd done this pipe but it doesn't work
there is an array of events and needs to bring only the events that have `dateStart` inside 30 days from now, how can I do it work? the compare of `dateStart` and `Date.now()` + 30 days

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SupplyEvent } from "../../models/supplyEvent";

@Pipe({
  name: 'toBeginFilter'
})
export class ToBeginFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  toBegin (SupplyEvent) {
    if (SupplyEvent.dateStart >= Date.now() + (30)) {
      return SupplyEvent
    }
  }

  transform(SupplyEvents: SupplyEvent[]): any {
    if (!SupplyEvents) return SupplyEvents
    return SupplyEvents.filter(this.toBegin)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share input/output format & related code

Comment: you mean, the HTML and component?  the thing is in the pipe, I need only bring elements that it inside 30 days from now, inside an array that it's imported and declared in the pipe, if I delete ´>= Date.now() + (30)´ it works, so I only ask how can I do it work, that filter

Answer (score 1):

Oops, not `3` ! JavaScript date object is based on timestamp.

> 30 Days = 30*24*3600*1000

```
export class ToBeginFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  // assuming SupplyEvent.dateStart is timestamp.
  toBegin (SupplyEvent) {
    return Date.now() - SupplyEvent.dateStart <= (30*24*3600*1000);
  }

  transform(SupplyEvents: SupplyEvent[]): any {
    if (!SupplyEvents) return SupplyEvents
    return SupplyEvents.filter(this.toBegin)
  }
}
```